# Auto discorver node.js server on local network via app

Tags: android, ios, node.js, sockets, networking

I'm building an app to stream audio between multiple clients with a node js server as relay, like a voice chat room, where one is the group creator and others can join. But the server is going to sit on a network where the ip is not static.
What is the best way to make the android/ios app locate the server ? Like when your phone finds a chromecast on the network ?

My own thought was to make the server broadcast a UDP package with the server ip and then make the android app authenticate with the server via a web socket, but i'm not quite sure if this is the best way to do it.

**Example flow of server/client connection:**

1. Server is booted.
2. App discovers server in the background.
3. App authenticates with the server.
4. App makes it possible to make a "group".
5. App sends information to server.
6. Server creates the "group" and makes it available to other clients.